# cordova requirements android target not installed: Command failed with ENOENT

Tags: android, cordova, apk

C:\Users\user\starwarssite>cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: not installed
Command failed with ENOENT: android list target
spawn android ENOENT
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Gradle: installed C:\Users\user\gradle-7.2\bin\gradle.BAT

I've attempted to delete android then re-install it back but that method doesn't seem to work I keep getting the same error. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.